# How to access a specific component/method in a class without creating an instance

Tags: java, oop

I have a class `GuiApplication` and a class `ImageHandler`. The GUI can work with the `ImageHandler` (and thus images) trough a class called `Crawler` which provides a façade for the methods the GUI can use.

There's a separate class called `StartUp` which has a main method and the only thing done there is create an instance of `GuiApplication` (so basically it starts the program).

In my GUI, there is a `JTextPane` which serves as a logger: certain actions and events will be shown there. With output that comes from elsewhere within my GUI, I can easily update its value. However, when there is output that comes from within my domain classes, e.g. `ImageHandler`, I can't do anything.

There is a `Try-Catch` block which prevents my program from crashing when an unexpected image URL passes trough my reader, and when it does I would like to show this in the textpane ("Error: File xxx could not be read").

However, I don't see an elegant way to communicate this to my GUI: I can't create an instance because that would create a new GUI and I don't think approaching my GUI trough the `StartUp` file is good practice either.

I was considering defining the variable in a different class that could be accessed troughout the entire project, but I wanted some opinions first.

Comment: Sounds like poor design of the facade. I'd add a _checked_ exception, per Joop's answer, and I'd consider interfacing the GUI directly with the ImageHandler - a facade is useful when it wraps a library, do you really need a wrapper for just one class? You should not define a global variable, it is bad practice.

Comment: There is currently also a class with methods concerning the connection to a specific webpage and I am planning to add similar stuff like a VideoHandler as well, so I believed a façade to be appropriate with the eye on additional functionality. I will brush up on my Exceptions, they seem to be the way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical way is to throw a RuntimeException, which does not need to change the methods' signature. Catch it in the GUI and do a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.

The other way is to extend the API of ImageHandler with an event handler, and install a message handler that calls in GuiApplication JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.

Answer (score 0):

One option that comes to mind is a callback: pass an instance (it can be an anonymous class) of some interface to the method doing the work, which it calls when an error occurs.